# How do I set the top margin on a nested div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to nest a div tag and set `margin-top` so that it sets the distance from the top of the inner div to the top of the outer element. However, when try the code below, there is no margin between the top of the nested element, rather the margin applies to the top of the outer element.

```css
      .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 110px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .title {
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-size: 30px;
      }
```

```html
 

    <div class="header">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add overflow: hidden; to .header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block` to `.header` will make it wrap around `.title` and margin will be relative to the parent div.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
.title {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
     background-color:gray;
     display: inline-block;
     clear:both;
     }
  .title {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
   
  }
```

or

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
     background-color:gray;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
  .title {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
   
  }
```

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
     background-color:gray;
     overflow: hidden;
     }
  .title {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
   
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/bt5ofu9m/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your style may help you

```css
      .header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 110px;
        text-align: center;
        display: table;
         margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .title {
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-size: 30px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```